# Excel MDX CubeSet Except() Returns Blank When Referenced By CubeValue

Tags: excel, mdx, cube

I have three tuples that I am reporting on, and I want to create an "All Other" set. I am using the following MDX query to exclude the set of the three tuples from the set of the crossjoin of the two tuple dimensions.

```
Except(
    {
        ([Table1].[Dim1].Children*[Table2].[Dim2].Children)
    },  {
        ([Table1].[Dim1].&[Apples],[Table2].[Dim2].&[Grocery]),
        ([Table1].[Dim1].&[Oranges],[Table2].[Dim2].Members),
        ([Table1].[Dim1].&[Pears],[Table2].[Dim2].Members)
    }
)
```

This returns a valid cubeset with 1,524 members, as expected. However, when this cubeset is passed to a cubevalue function in another cell, a blank value is returned. I have validated that there should be data within the resulting "All Other" set, and that the cubevalue measure is functioning on other sets (both single-tuple and multiple-tuple).

I have also tried a simple negation (`-{tuple set}`), but this returns a #N/A error rather than a valid set.

Thoughts on what the issue could be or alternate ways to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Not a definite answer but to help with investigation.

If you rather hardcode the `MDX` into the `CUBEVALUE` function does it return a value - I don't know the name of your cube or any of the measures in it so you'll need to replace these values:

```
=CUBEVALUE("MYCUBENAME", ,"[Measures].[MYMEASURENAME]", "Except(
    {
        ([Table1].[Dim1].Children*[Table2].[Dim2].Children)
    },  {
        ([Table1].[Dim1].&[Apples],[Table2].[Dim2].&[Grocery]),
        ([Table1].[Dim1].&[Oranges],[Table2].[Dim2].Members),
        ([Table1].[Dim1].&[Pears],[Table2].[Dim2].Members)
    }
)" )
```

If you try just members rather than tuples does it work?:

```
=CUBEVALUE("MYCUBENAME", ,"[Measures].[MYMEASURENAME]", 
    "Except(
      [Table1].[Dim1].Children, 
      [Table1].[Dim1].&[Apples]
     )" )
```

Comment: No dice. I even tried simplifying to only excluding a single tuple, hardcoded in the `CUBEVALUE()` function. I'm wondering if this is a limitation of the OLAP server I am working with (Power BI Service).